# What are the earliest areas that will still provide decent XP for a level 45?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm currently having some problems with Belial on Nightmare, and I've decided I need to farm a bit to gain another level before tackling him again (and either get some new upgrades to drop, or farm enough gold while leveling to buy something good off the AH).

I'm looking to clear up some achievements while I'm doing it, so I'm considering farming some of the earliest areas of Act II, or possibly even late Act I, until I gain my level.

However, I would like to ensure that the monsters I am killing are the appropriate level for my character, and avoid going too far back and fighting mobs that aren't earning me some decent XP.

What is the earliest area that I can fight monsters as a level 45 while still making progress towards level 46?

Comment: By level, do you mean Act, or individual area within an act? Presumably the range of monsters in Act 1 on Normal can be anywhere between 1 and 15, depending on where you choose to pick a fight.

Comment: Sorry, I meant each area within the Acts.  I'm assuming there's a fairly well defined range within each Act, presumably with distinct ranges for the various areas (i.e. Dahlgur Oasis would likely be different levels than Black Canyon Mines, even though both are in Act II).

Comment: Also, note that as you go higher and higher up the difficulty chain it's less useful to give a breakdown of difficulty by area, since the level differences are very small. Generally, if you're progressing linearly through the game and don't skip ahead, your level will be at around those of the monsters and so instead loot is going to be what determines whether or not your character is suitable for an area.

Comment: @MarkTrapp Fair enough.  I'll edit to focus on the specific issue I'm facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hit the **'Public Games'** button in the main menu in order to look at which quests are selectable.

When you select a public quest, the description contains a level range. And if Blizzard recommends an area, I bet your character will still get experience in that area.

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions you need to answer in order to come to a conclusion.

1. What class are you? Are you planning to Solo or Party?

Some classes are better at soloing than partying. For example, a well geared Wizard is much better at soloing than other classes due to the large amount of CC and AOE a Wizard has.

2. Do you have the right gear?

At level 45, as a Wizard, I had approximately 2.5k Damage, 1.5k Armor, and 5k HP. If you are well below these stats, consider hitting the Auction House to gear up, maybe that's all you need.

3. Are you using the right abilities?

Some abilities such as Diamond Skin and Magic Weapon are irreplaceable for a Wizard, perhaps you should find a compendium of builds for your class.

Hope I've helped!

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question. I'm not asking "how can I do better".  I'm asking "what are the easiest monsters that will still give me xp, because I want to go back and work on some achievements in earlier areas while leveling."

Comment: Apologies, I thought that giving suggestions for how you could do better would solve the root problem of not being able to kill Belial. Anyhow, the most experience gained in the game is through the Act 3 End boss to Act 4 First boss quest chain. However, you aren't there yet, so I would suggest hitting the AH to get a high level of Damage and then doing farm runs of the Butcher. By level 45, I was able to kill the Butcher in under 10 seconds.

Comment: But does the Butcher (and the monsters leading up to him) give decent XP at 45? That's the root of the question. If you could edit to prOvide info on that, id appreciate it. Incidentally, the problem I was having w Belial was that I focused too much on int gear (I'm a wd), and neglected my vitality. Ive already tripled my health, and should have no problem with him now. But there's still some achievements I want to clear up first.